# Parametrized remote trigger with multiline string Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins job which triggers a remote job. Both the jobs have a multiline string as paramter.
I am not able to pass the parameter to the remote job. Only the first line of my input string is passed to the remote job.

Is it not possible to trigger a remote job with multiline string?

```
  def parameters = 'ip_range='
  params.ip_range.readLines().each{
     parameters = parameters + "${it}" + "\n"
  }
  parameters = parameters + "\n"+'remote_branch='+env.BRANCH_NAME
```

also tried
def parameters = 'ip_range=' + params.ip_range + "\n"+'remote_branch='+env.BRANCH_NAME

Both cases only the first value is passed on as paramter to the remote job.

> Console output of jenkins job from either methods
>
> - parameters:              [ip_range=1.2.4.5/20, 1.56.23.12/32, remote_branch=21.4.0/INSURECI-203156]

EDIT: remote trigger

```
                        triggerRemoteJob (
                            abortTriggeredJob: true,
                            enhancedLogging: true,
                            job: "some-remote-url/job/ip-range-test/job/${remoteTriggerBranchName}",
                            parameters: parameters,
                            remoteJenkinsName: 'Openshift',
                            useCrumbCache: true,
                            useJobInfoCache: true,
                            maxConn: 5
                        );
```

Comment: show the code where you triggering remote job

Comment: @daggett: updated question with remote trigger

Comment: you have to ask plugin developer

Comment: I will try. Right now i m calling the remote job within  a foreach

Answer (score 0):

It won't work as is because the parameterized remote trigger plugin uses `'\n'` as a delimiter for parameters.

A possible way around this would be to create a Token Macro which would expand to the new line character. Token Macro expansion is done after the parameters are split on `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I struggled with this one too.
I opened two PRs on the original repository to improve parameters handling and they've been accepted.

Hopefully, it should be released soon (version 3.1.6.1) and when that's done, you can pass a Map in the parameters field with whatever as a value, including multi-line strings.

It would look like:

```
triggerRemoteJob (
  job: "MyProduct/Release",
  parameters: [
    'MULTI_LINE_PARAM': '''\
      line1
      line2
      line3
    '''.stripIndent()
  ],
  remoteJenkinsName: 'MyCompanyJenkins'
)
```

See the [release page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/releases) and the [corresponding JIRA issue](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-68737).